# Iterating through a list of numbers and strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops

Suppose I have a list `['a', '1','student']` in Python

I am iterating through this list and want to check which item in the list is numeric.
I have tried `all(item.isdigit())`, `type(item)==str`. but shows error.

note: Numeric values in list are enclosed in quotes so they are identified as strings.
How to get past that?

I am expecting to identify which item in list is numeric and which are alphabetical values. The challenge is the numeric values are enclosed in quotes identifying them as strings

Comment: Are you after a truth array of each value? `[False,True,False]`?

Comment: What is your definition of "numeric"? Are they only integers? Do decimals count? What about negative numbers? Complex numbers?

Comment: @Selcuk for now , i have only integers in list. no decimals , no negative.

Comment: You should have shown all your code.  `isdigit()` sounds like exactly what you need, although I don't know why you wrapped it in `all`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are after an array of bools, you can use:

```py
lst = ['a', '1', 'student']
y = [x.isdigit() for x in lst]
```

```
>>> y
[False, True, False]
```

Where `x.isdigit()` returns true if the string `x` represents a digit. You can also use `[x.isnumeric() for x in lst]` if you are after any string that is numeric. Which includes decimals.

Comment: i have do some operation on integers if its represents digits

Comment: Thank you, also one doubt,
it its true , i want to remove the quotes from '1 ' integer, and save into a new list. how to remove the quotes?

Comment: you can cast (convert) a string `'1'` into an int by using `int('i')`. To get all the numbers from your list use: `[int(x) for x in lst if x.isdigit()]`

Comment: i am getting TypeError: can only join an iterable, if i typecasted to int

Comment: Make sure you use `[int(x) for x in lst if x.isdigit()]`. Because if you do `int("a")` or any non number string, you will get the TypeError

Comment: newlist=(','.join(int(item) for item in vlist if item.isdigit()))
i did this, i am getting error TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found

Comment: Use `','.join(x for x in vlist if x.isdigit())`

Comment: is there a way to add an else in the above join function?

Comment: Found it, use `print(','.join(x if x.isdigit() else "HERE" for x in vlist))`. Where `HERE` is the else

Answer (score 0):

Try `isdigit()` instead:

```
l = ['a', '1', 'student']
for item in l:
    if item.isdigit():
        print(f'{item} is a digit')
    elif item.isalpha():
        print(f'{item} is a letter')
```

Answer (score 0):

In the example you gave, extracting a list containing all the numbers is done by:

```
myList = ['a', '1','student']
onlyNumbers = [x for x in myList if x.isdigit()]
print(onlyNumbers)
```

An important distinction to make is the difference between a "number" type (int, float or Decimal) and a string that represents the number. If you had a list containing items of both string and integer types, then you could extract the items by altering the previous example like so:

```
myList = ['a', 1,'student']
onlyNumbers = [x for x in myList if isinstance(x,int)]
print(onlyNumbers)
```

Note how the 1 is no longer quoted. This means that it is a integer type.

Here are some recommendations:

```
all(iterable,condition)
```

returns a single value indicating whether ALL values in an iterable are true. It does not extract all values which are true, which is a misconception you appear to have.

Instead of `type(x)==str`, you can do `isinstance(x,str)` which is slightly cleaner.

To extract numbers from strings, you can use regular expressions. Alternatively, it is easier to attempt to convert the string to that number type:

```
anInteger = int("13")
aFloat = float("1")+float("1.2")
aComplex = complex("1+1j")
```

This is an example to show it working in full. It relies on python's numeric types throwing an exception when a bad representation of that type is passed to the type's constuctor.

```
def isNumberType(repStr : str, numType):
    try:
        numType(repStr)
        return True
    except:
        return False
x = ["12.32","12","ewa"]
onlyIntegers = [int(val) for val in x if isNumberType(val,int)]
print(onlyIntegers)
```